# Guzzle Maintaining Cookies

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm creating an API for a site that allows the user to login via the API. I'm using Guzzle, but the question is how do I use the Cookies Plugin with Guzzle? In cURL I can use a cookie file, and pass this along with requests. But the example on the Guzzle docs looks confusing.

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookiePlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Cookie\CookieJar\ArrayCookieJar;

$cookiePlugin = new CookiePlugin(new ArrayCookieJar());

// Add the cookie plugin to a client
$client = new Client('http://www.test.com/');
$client->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);

// Send the request with no cookies and parse the returned cookies
$client->get('http://www.yahoo.com/')->send();

// Send the request again, noticing that cookies are being sent
$request = $client->get('http://www.yahoo.com/');
$request->send();

echo $request;
```

It seems to be making 3 requests. I don't understand why it's making a request to test.com, then twice to yahoo.com. Why are you not able to make 1 request?

Comment: why don't you remove the other lines of code and stick with 1 request

Comment: The code above is from the docs. I don't understand why it's making 3 requests. I'm with you, why doesn't it just make the 1 request.

Comment: maybe it's to show you different ways of making requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just an example... You don't have to make three requests. Just attach the cookie plugin to your client and you're good.